# How do I add a curved border to different sections of my HTML?

Tags: html, css, border

I'm learning uikit and trying to add curved borders to different sections of my page, but I can't figure it out.

The example I'm trying to follow looks like this, which is how I'd like it to look:

[image]

```css
header{background-color:#000000;width:100%;height:200px;font-size:100px;text-align:center;}
nav{background-color:#000000;width:20%;height:1300px;float:left;font-size:20px;text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF;}
section {background-color:#CCCC99; width:80%;height:1300px;float:left;font-size:20px;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
  <title>4WAP - Exercise1</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit.css" /> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyles.css" />
  <script src="jquery/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/uikit.min.js"></script> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
 <header></header> 
  <nav> 
 <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">
 <h3 class="uk-panel-title">This is the Main Menu</h3>
 <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-side uk-nav-parent-icon" data-uk-nav> <!--main menu start--> 
 <li class="uk-parent"><a href="#">Main Option One - Click Me To See More or Less</a>
 <ul class="uk-nav-sub">
 <li><a href="#">More One</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">More Two</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Main Option Two</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Main Option Three</a></li>
 </ul></div>
 </nav>
 <section></section>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Can you guys give me a hand? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

using uikit you can add the `.uk-border-rounded` class to a element. or manually add `border-radius:5px;` to a elements css.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving different type of curved bordered divs:

```css
.normal{
  position:absolute;
  left:5px;
  top:5px;
  width:100px; 
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
  border-radius:10px;
}
.medium{
  position:absolute;
  left:15px;
  top:15px;
  width:100px; 
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid green;
  border-radius:30px;
}
.rounded{
  position:absolute;
  left:25px;
  top:25px;
  width:100px; 
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="normal"></div>
<div class="medium"></div>
<div class="rounded"></div>
```